# How to terminate reactiveTimer in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, terminate

I want to run some code in loop each n-seconds based on user input. I do it with reactiveTimer().
App is reading from file but when there is nothing more to read or user clicked on button, I want to terminate the loop.

my code seems on server side as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$start, {
    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(input$timerValue)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
         autoInvalidate()
         ...code...
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want to definitely stop the timer, you can set it to `reactiveTimer(Inf)` otherwise you need keep it running and you can use a boolean to store its status on and off, like in following example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(textOutput("mytext"),
                      actionButton("s0","manual"),
                      actionButton("s1","start"),
                      actionButton("s2","stop"),
                      actionButton("s3","terminate")),
         server=function(input, output){
           my<-reactiveValues(inc=0, timer=reactiveTimer(100), started=FALSE)

           observeEvent(input$s0, {my$inc<-my$inc+1})
           observeEvent(input$s1, {my$started<-TRUE})
           observeEvent(input$s2, {my$started<-FALSE})
           observeEvent(input$s3, {my$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)})

           observe({
             my$timer()
             if(isolate(my$started))
               my$inc<-isolate(my$inc)+1
             })

           output$mytext <- renderText(my$inc)
         })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works great, thats what I was finding ;)

Comment: Hi, @HubertL could you say why the isolate was necessary in the if condition?

Comment: Hi @ankit, both `isolate()`s avoid triggering the observe event when updating `inc` or `started`, and only the `timer` triggers the event.